# Odd artifact when attempting to convert an image to polar and back in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

In attempting to convert an image back from polar to rectangular, I can't get my code to cover every angle in the polar image, so I have attempted to solve this by converting the image back by each half, but I end up getting a line artifact in the middle of the image. I want to know how to get the conversion to work for all angles when going from polar to cartesian.

```
img = imread('trees.tif');
% img=img';

%% Cart2pol

[m,n]=size(img);
m0=floor(m/2);
n0=floor(n/2);

% [idx,mp]=gray2double(img,32);

x=(1:n)-(n/2);
y=(1:m)-(m/2);

[xp,yp]=meshgrid(linspace(0,2*pi,3000),linspace(0,400,3000));

[xx,yy]=pol2cart(xp,yp);

img=double(img);
out=interp2(x,y,img,xx,yy);

figure(1)
imshow(out,[])

%% pol 2 cart

x=(1:n)-(n/2);
y=(1:m)-(m/2);
r=linspace(0,-2*pi,3000);
t=linspace(0,400,3000);

[xc,yc]=meshgrid(x,y);
[xx,yy]=cart2pol(xc,yc);

out1=interp2(r,t,out,xx,yy);
out1(isnan(out1))=0;
out1=flipud(out1);


out2=interp2(r,t,fliplr(out),xx,yy);
out2(isnan(out2))=0;

done = out1+out2;

figure(2)
subplot(2,2,1);imshow(out1,[])

subplot(2,2,2);imshow(out2,[])

subplot(2,2,3);imshow(img,[])

subplot(2,2,4);imshow(done,[])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to center `x`, `y` correctly around axis origin.

Replace:
`x=(1:n)-(n/2);`
`y=(1:m)-(m/2);`

With:

`x=(1:n)-(n/2) - 0.5;`
`y=(1:m)-(m/2) - 0.5;`

Result after correction:
[image: Result after correction]

Result before correction:
[image: Result before correction]

Comment: Thanks! This appears to work well for landscape aspect ratio and square images, so if I use vertical ones I will just rotate them.